# Using Roxio VHS to DVD 3 Plus on Arch Linux

Tags: v4l

I bought https://www.roxio.com/en/products/easy-vhs-to-dvd/standard/ with the goal of converting VHS tapes to a digital format.

https://superuser.com/questions/234026/video-from-vhs-via-usb-capture-device-on-linux seems to imply that I should be looking for a V4L2 device.  (I assume something like /dev/vbio)

```
$ dmesg | tail

[241892.285109] usb 1-9: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[241892.428076] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=1b80, idProduct=e31d, bcdDevice= 1.00
[241892.428081] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[241892.428085] usb 1-9: Product: Roxio Video Capture USB
[241892.428088] usb 1-9: SerialNumber: 11111111111111111111
[241892.500539] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
```

At this point, I have not gotten what I expected.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31672172#31672172 seems to imply this problem has been solved.

What's missing?  How do I connect this to VLC?

--- EDIT 1 ---

https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/RoxioEasyVHStoDVD#Making_it_Work implies I need `em28xx`.

```
$ sudo modprobe em28xx
```

unplug usb, replug usb

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1b80:e31d Afatech 

$ dmesg | grep em28xx
[246616.297845] usbcore: registered new interface driver em28xx
```

From https://superuser.com/questions/234026/video-from-vhs-via-usb-capture-device-on-linux, I was expecting dmesg to give me multiple entries, and again, the device.

--- EDIT 2 ---

The audio does seem to work.

```
$ arecord -l
card 2: USB [Roxio Video Capture USB], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Asked here, too: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240660

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I've concluded that this doesn't work and likely never will.  If you haven't this device yet, and you need it to work with Linux: don't buy it.